# "dyld: Library not loaded', "reason: Image not found" error in Swift 2.2 iOS with watch

Tags: swift, frameworks

I have loaded the Cardio and Result frameworks, with Carthage, and added it to linked binaries and embedded frameworks. I have added the 'copy new files' in Build Phases. It is showing the 'suitcase' icons for the frameworks in my iOS target, watch target and watch extension. The app builds but then crashes before loading any scenes on my watch.

The console error says

```
 "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Cardio.framework/Cardio referenced from" (my realm database)  then " Reason: image not found"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?

Comment: Hi @MarcoSantarossa, yes I had, unfortunately that hadn't solved it.

Answer (score 8):

Try this In Xcode,

1) On your application targets’ `Build Phases` settings tab, click the `+` icon and choose `New Run Script Phase`. Create a Run Script in which you specify your shell (ex: `bin/sh`), add the following contents to the script area below the shell:

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
```

2) and add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under `Input Files`, e.g.:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Cardio.framework
```

Comment: Thanks so much @AnilKumar, will try this then update here

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion @AnilKumar, unfortunately it's made no change though, I'm still getting the same 'dyld: Library not loaded @rpath/Cardio.framework/Cardio .... image not found'  error when I run the app

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, one of your Carthage libraries has an additional dependency, one example is 'AWSAuthUI.framework' requires 'AWSAuthCore.framework', so in your case 'Cardio.framework' is a dependency of the Carthage library you have installed (Swift 5.1 in my case)